# Hide Header and Footer in PDF once a specific Table is Displayed (Netsuite)

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, netsuite, freemarker

Long time reader, first time questioner.

I'm a dev in training at a NetSuite company, and I got my first Adv PDF scripting job.

The client wants the header and footer displayed to be displayed on a purchase order that has the item table. But then the document prints barcodes, and when it prints barcodes they want the header and footer hidden.

That doesn't happen at any fixed page number, and all the similar questions I've seen asked are at a fixed page.

So what do I do?

I looked but haven't found anything that seems to answer my question.

Comment: In template you can add if and else condition above the header .

Answer (score 0):

You can use **if condition for item table** in header as per your requirement. Here I am writing sample code for better understanding.

```
    <macrolist>
        <#if record.item?has_content>   
        <macro id="nlheader">
            <table class="header" style="width: 100%; font-size: 10pt;"><tr>
 <td align="left"><#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0><img height="45px" src="${companyInformation.logoUrl}" vertical-align="top" width="200px" /></#if></td>
    <td align="right"><span class="title">Bill of Lading</span></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
    <td align="right"><barcode bar-width="1" marginright="0" margin="0" padding-left="387px" align ="right" codetype="code128" showtext="true" value="${record.tranid}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">${record.trandate}</td>
        </tr></table>
        </macro>
        <macro id="nlfooter">
            <table style="width: 100%; font-size: 10pt;">
     <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2" style="padding: 0;"><pagenumber/> of <totalpages/></td>
    </tr></table>
        </macro>
      </#if>
    </macrolist>
```

I hope it will help you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Set the default header/footer in the body element and then, after your items `<#list>`, use a page break (`<pbr>`) to override with a blank header/footer. See the BFO docs for the [FOOTER and HEADER attribute](https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/footer.html):

> [The footer and header attributes] can be used either on the BODY tag to set the default header/footer for all pages, [or] the PBR tag to set it for pages following that page break

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<pdf>
 <head>
  <macrolist>
    <macro id="empty-macro">
       <!-- no content -->
    </macro>
    <macro id="default-header">
       <!-- regular header content goes here -->
    </macro>
    <macro id="default-footer">
       <!-- regular footer content goes here -->
    </macro>
  </macrolist>
 </head>
 <body header="default-header" header-height="40pt" footer="default-footer" footer-height="20pt">
   <#list record.items as item>
     <!-- items list -->
   </#list>
   <pbr header="empty-macro" header-height="0pt" footer="empty-macro" footer-height="0pt">
   <!-- barcodes list -->
 </body>
</pdf>
```